# How to satisfy: Import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;

Tags: java, apache, ant

In NetBeans or at the command-line, how do I get what is needed to satisfy this Import?

Comment: Add import statement in java file?

Comment: You need to have the ant jar apache-ant-1.8.2.jar (or later version )in your buid path http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/apache-ant/apache-ant-zip.jar.zip

Comment: @Clyde  ant -version shows I have 1.9.3 installed.  I can do Ant builds, but I can't do this:  Import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException  in my Java program.

Comment: These are two separate paths, so you need to set the path to the Ant jar in your classpath (or, depending on your IDE, your build path as CJ Croix mentioned). The end result would be something like this in your  path: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ant-1.7.1.jar"/>`

Answer (score 0):

you can download it from
[http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapacheant182jar.htm][1]
and insert in project structure